# CUDA - GB/s for PCI-E vs Gbps for memory clock speed for GPUs

Tags: cuda, gpu, bandwidth, pci-e

I'm astounded at PCI-E 3.0 speed: ~16 GB/s (gigabytes per second) against top gamma GPUs memory clock speed (a Titan X lists ~10 Gbps i.e. giga-bits per second)

So we have

```
PCI-E 3.0    16 GB/s
Titan X      ~1 GB/s
```

So the question is: **why is there this abysmal difference?** They often say in regard to CUDA that PCI-E is the biggest hurdle at harnessing GPU power but it seems the contrary: PCI-E can handle way bigger loads than GPU memory can (even PCI-E is ~8 GB/s)

Is my reasoning flawed somehow?

Comment: Clear question, downvoted for no reason (none given). Thanks.

Comment: You mean "Clearly off topic question". I've voted to close this -- it is clearly about hardware, and it is completely wrong and nonsensical anyway.

Comment: I didn't see superuser a great fit since it's mostly regarding CUDA notions, anyway care to explain why you think it's nonsensical? I can't make sense if I don't get it first

Comment: The [10 gigabit/s value](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/titan-x-pascal/#specs) is *per-pin*. With a 384 bit wide memory interface this amounts to a total theoretical memory bandwidth of 480 GB/sec. Actually achievable values are about 80% of that, both for PCIe and memory.

Comment: This is a hardware spec question and nothing more than that, that's why it is off topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [10 gigabit/s memory bandwidth value](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/titan-x-pascal/#specs) for the TITAN X is *per-pin*. With a 384 bit wide memory interface this amounts to a total theoretical peak memory bandwidth of 480 GB/sec. Practically achievable values are about 80% of the theoretical peak bandwidth, both for memory and PCIe as well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it instead of just downvoting.

Comment: a 384-bit pci-e would consume a lot power.

Comment: Surely it would. That might be one reason why it doesn't exist.